# Subdomains on WampServer

Tags: domains, apache, subdomain

I'm working on WampServer for development, I've set up the domain tuniguide.local and it works fine with this configuration:

DocumentRoot "D:\www\tuniguide"

ServerName tuniguide.local

But when I wanted to add a subdomain fr.tuniguide.local I get a 404 Not Found with this configuration:

DocumentRoot "D:\www\tuniguide\fr"

ServerName fr.tuniguide.local

It gives me this message:
The requested URL /www/tuniguide/index.php was not found on this server.

Is there someting that I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: I think i can check and tell you

Comment: weird that your documentroot and URL's have the same prefix.  Try reading your errorlog and re-checking the filesystem

Answer (score 3):

I think Virtual Hosts and updating your hosts file would help in this case. In your server config file, you'll want to make sure it's turned on for your port with this line:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Then you want to specify each virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:\www\tuniguide"
  ServerName tuniguide.local

  # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:\www\tuniguide\fr"
  ServerName fr.tuniguide.local

  # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Then finally you'll want to update your host file to include something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 tuniguide.local
127.0.0.1 fr.tuniguide.local
```

Note: Be sure to restart Apache after you've updated both the config and hosts file.